# Why in Ramayana, Rama is referred as Raghuvamsha?

Tags: vedas, ramayana, advaita, vaishnavism, sri-vaishnava

In Ramayana, there are many Kings before Lord Rama.

But yet, while referring in certain places, why only it is said as Raghu-vamsha and Ishvaku clan?

Why Raghu and Ishvaku are referred, leaving the other Kings?

Can someone explain?

Comment: Raghuvaṁśa means the vaṁśa (family/clan) of Raghus. The other kings are not left, there is Sāgara, Dilīpa and so on..  Ikṣvāku is the founder of the solar dynasty and the ancestor of many royal families, even that of Janaka, Sītā's foster father.

Comment: Raghu was a famous king, and his royal descendants addressed them as being from Raghukula or Raghuvaṁśī. This is not uncommon, even those of the candravaṁśa (lunar dynasty) called themselves as Bharatas, or Kuruvaṁśa. Both Bharata and Kuru were recognized kings.

Comment: But Raghu King was not the first King if we trace back to Lord Rama's lineage right? As you mentioned there are Kings Like Sagara and others? Why is it not Sagaravamsha, but Raghuvamsha? Can you please clarify? @Bingming

Comment: Good question, but I don't know the answer to this. One can ask the same question that why Bhīṣma and others are called Kuruvaṁśī and thus Kauravas rather than Puruvaṁśī? Such questions I don't think can be answered. But the popularity of Raghuvaṁśa other than Rāmāyaṇa is also due to Kālidāsa's mahākāvya Raghuvaṁśa, it may have some relation I guess.